# How to use `typed/racket` in `scribble/lp`

Tags: racket, literate-programming, typed-racket, scribble

Is it possible to use other `#lang`s in `#lang scribble/lp` for literate programming?

For example, I want to use `#lang typed/racket` in `#lang scribble/lp`. How to realize that?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: There are two ways. First, you can simply **put your code in a submodule**, and require it immediately. Second, you can use [**my fork of `scribble/lp2`**](https://github.com/jsmaniac/hyper-literate/tree/stackoverflow-q-18877881), which allows you to specify the underlying module language.

---

## First method

Due to [an issue](https://github.com/racket/scribble/issues/15), you'll have to wrap the whole thing in a `(begin …)`, although there's a pull request which should fix this on the way.

```
#lang scribble/lp2

@chunk[<*>
       (begin
         (module main typed/racket
           (define a : Number 1)
           (provide a)
           (module moo racket/base '…)
           (module+ test
             (require typed/rackunit)
             (check-equal? a (+ 1/2 1/2))))

         (require 'main)
         (provide (all-from-out 'main))

         (module test typed/racket
           (require (submod ".." main test))))]
```

Bear in mind that these are submodule, so you can't put your `test` module inside `main`, as it won't be executed. Here, I have a `(module+ test …)` inside `main`, and it is required by a `test` module at the root level. If the `(module test` at the root is commented out, then the tests won't be executed.

The same concern applies also when requiring `moo` from another module, you'll have to use `(require (submod "myfile.lp2.typed.rkt" main moo))`, or make an "alias" like is done above for `test` and `main`.

Keep also in mind that the more nested a submodule is, the more times it gets visited and/or instantiated (not sure which). This can have a serious impact on the loading speed in typed/racket programs, as they are already themselves visited and/or instantiated multiple times. You can see this by adding `(begin-for-syntax (displayln 'executed))` in your code, it gets printed many times.

## Second method

My fork of `scribble/lp2`, [hyper-literate](https://github.com/jsmaniac/hyper-literate/tree/stackoverflow-q-18877881) (for hypertext literate programming) only alters `scribble/lp2` and relies on the original version of `scribble` for the rest.

I don't guarantee backwards compatibility, as I'm currently fixing some bugs and adding extra features like being able to re-print a `chunk` to refresh the reader's memory, etc. The `stackoverflow-q-18877881` branch I linked to should remain stable, though. Newer stuff will go in [`master`](https://github.com/jsmaniac/hyper-literate).

Here's a small example file. There's [a more complete example in `test/test.hl.rkt`](https://github.com/jsmaniac/hyper-literate/blob/stackoverflow-q-18877881/test/test.hl.rkt):

```
#lang hyper-literate/typed typed/racket/base

@(require (for-label typed/racket/base
                     typed/rackunit))

@title{Title}

Hello world.

@chunk[<*>
       (require typed/rackunit)

       ;; Would give an error as typed/racket/base is used on the #lang line:
       ;curry

       (check-equal? ((make-predicate One) 1) #t)

       (define (f [x : 'e123]) x)

       (define ee (ann (f 'e123) 'e123))
       (provide ee)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear so, but you can use a typed/racket evaluator with scribble/eval.

```
    #lang scribble/manual
    @(require racket/sandbox
              scribble/eval)
    @(define my-evaluator
       (parameterize ([sandbox-output 'string]
                      [sandbox-error-output 'string])
         (make-evaluator 'typed/racket/base)))
    @interaction[#:eval my-evaluator

                 (: my-sqr (Real -> Real))
                 (define (my-sqr x)
                   (* x x))
                 (my-sqr 42)]
```

Example taken from [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/eval.html).